# Weak version of Hahn-Banach separation

Tags: real-analysis

Let $K\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a compact convex subset and $p\in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a point not in $K$. Then $p$ and $K$ can be strongly separated with a hyperplane $c_1 x_1+\cdots+c_nx_n=b$ (I mean "$c_1p_1+\cdots c_np_n <b$ and $c_1 k_1+\cdots c_nk_n > b$ forall $k\in K$").

I want to prove this statement for second year undergraduate students. I don't want to use functional analysis. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K \subseteq R^n$ be compact and convex and $p \not\in K$. Assume that there is a unique point $x_0 \in K$ that is closest to $p$ that is
\begin{equation}
||x_0 - p || = \min\limits_{x \in K} ||x - p||.
\end{equation}
Let $B$ denote the closed ball with center $p$ and radius $||x_0 - p|| > 0$. Then $B \cap K = \{x_0\}$ by uniqueness of the minimizer. Let $l$ denote the plane perpendicular to $p-x_0$ passing through $(p + x_0)/2$. Clearly $l \cap K = \varnothing$ by convexity of $K$ (this can also be seen graphically), so we've foudn a strongly separating hyperplane. That $x_0$ does in fact exist follows by continuity of the functional $x \mapsto ||x-p||$ over the compact set $K$. Uniqueness can be proven in a few lines using the standard argument involving the parallelogram rule.

Comment: Great! This proof is almost elementary and I love this.